# How can I get Twitter to serve compressed js?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, twitter

A Lighthouse audit of my site suggests: Text-based resources should be served with compression. Compression is enabled on my site. Everything is served compressed except js for my Twitter follow button.

I use an .htaccess file that enables compression. An abbreviated version is below. I also use Cloudflare.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/js
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/ld+json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-web-app-manifest+json
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain

# For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch MSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

I want to get Twitter to serve compressed js to shorten the load time of my page a bit. (Let me know if I should add any tags.)

Comment: is the particular js file hosted on your server or on twitter's? .htaccess and cloudflare only works for your domain/server

Comment: Twitter's. I have a follow button on the page which serves some js from Twitter. The jQuery from googleapis seems to be served compressed. I was hoping to find a way to force Twitter to honor the compression request in my .htaccess. Let me know if you have any ideas—thanks for responding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable gzip compression and leverage browser caching in Pinterest, Twitter and facebook Javascript files.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52804551/how-to-enable-gzip-compression-and-leverage-browser-caching-in-pinterest-twitte)

Comment: OK, looks like I can't do this, unfortunately. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.htaccess extends your apache webserver's capabilities such as providing server-side compression for local resources, however it will not work on remote resources that are loaded on the web page (such as remote CSS or Javascript inclusion).

Cloudflare for certain will not be able to minify or compress remote resources that are not being proxied through their network. Cloudflare can only minify or compress local resources in your own domain or subdomains that are orange-clouded DNS records, then cache them in their edge locations over CDN.

There's a third-party library like [Minimee](https://johndwells.github.io/Minimee/) that claims to be able to compress external resources, however the author advised against doing that: https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/support/minimee/viewthread/7835#26610